# System account and sharepoint farm account?

Tags: 2013

Hi what is the system account ?, when i login to any share point applications with share point farm account and application pool account login shows system account

Is system account run with windows account permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHAREPOINT\System account is the same account used by application pool of your SharePoint web application in IIS at the time of creation/extension of respective web application. This is the account which is used when you run your code in under elevated privileges by SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Other than this account, any other account which is Farm account or which you add in webapplication can be configured to run as system account.

sometimes System Account can be used so that the data modified under this account will display as Modified by System Account and not under any particular account.

Comment: How Sharepoint use system account internally to call resources ,database operations?

Comment: Via  normal database access..farm account has database access and hence when something dunga under elevated privilege it uses this account to make operation rather than using normal user logged in account...